# Jpa repository filter by enum value

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, orm, persistence

```
public class EmployeeEntity {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Length(min = 2, max = 30)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Length(min = 2, max = 30)
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
@Length(max = 50)
private String email;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
private Set<EmployeeRoleEntity> roles;}
```

This is my Employee class and as you can see inside Employee, I have a set of EmployeeRoleEntity

```
public class EmployeeRoleEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "role_name")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private RoleEntityEnum role;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
@ToString.Exclude
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
private EmployeeEntity employee;
```

I was trying to filter my employees depends in their role. I created a method like this on my Jpa repository;

```
List<EmployeeEntity> findByRoles_RoleContainingIgnoreCase( String role);
```

But it doesn't work and Im so confused to what to do. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer;

```
List<EmployeeEntity> findByRoles_Role( RoleEntityEnum role);
```

This solved my problem. I thought at first the problem was the method but appearently the problem was parameter.